# jQuery Mobile: Two/three column vertical control group of radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've been working with jQuery Mobile lately and have begun to hit various limitations; most of which I can work around using some sort of jQuery/Javascript/CSS manipulation. We're using a lot of iPads, which allows for more width than your typical phone. Some input groups on our pages tend to look better in a two column format; when possible.

An example is a long list of radio buttons. It looks bad in only one column. We'd like to display the radio button lists in 2 or 3 colunms, instead of the typical 1 column format that you get with a single "vertical" "controlgroup". See the vertical control group on this demo page:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/checkboxradio-radio/#Verticalgroup

With checkboxes, I've accomplished this by creating two or three different controlgroups and then placing them into a 3 column grid. This works well with checkboxes, but I'm not sure how to do this with radio buttons. Any ideas?

I assume I could create three different radio input vertical control groups (side by side) and then manipulate the CSS so it looks like there are one group. I'd have to manage a hidden input for the actual selected radio.

Comment: Personally, I find using bootstrap to design for mobile to be a much more agreeable task

Comment: Noted. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with jQuery Mobile for this project.

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle showing what you did for the checkboxes?

Comment: Probably not the best question for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create two columns for the marketing source; right and left. The names are "marketing_source_left" and "marketing_source_right". I populate the two radio vertical control groups and then use jQuery to change both to have the "name" property of just "marketing_source".

```
// Define current marketing_source value and remove hidden field
var marketing_source = $('#marketing_form #marketing_source').val(); // hidden field
$('#marketing_form #marketing_source').val(marketing_source).remove();

// Change all marketing source radios (left and right sides)
// to have property name="marketing_source"
$("#marketing_form input:radio[name='marketing_source_left']").prop('name', 'marketing_source').prop('checked', false);
$("#marketing_form input:radio[name='marketing_source_right']").prop('name', 'marketing_source').prop('checked', false);

// Set the radio to checked for the marketing source value
$('#marketing_form input[type="radio"]:checked').prop('checked', false); // Uncheck current
$('#marketing_form input:radio[name="marketing_source"]').filter('[value="'+marketing_source+'"]').prop('checked', true);
$('#marketing_form input:radio[name="marketing_source"]').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

The CSS used was something similar to this.

```
#marketing_right_div, #marketing_left_div {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 314px !important;
    text-align: top;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```